# SQL: Help using GROUP BY (or other?) to select COUNT of unique PARENT+CHILD+MAX(CREATED_DT) records

Tags: sql, group-by

For the following data set, I am attempting to select the combinations of PARENT+CHILD+COUNT where CREATED_DT is greatest. I am assuming GROUP BY is the correct way to get at this, but I've had no luck. Any thoughts?

```
PARENT  CHILD  COUNT  CREATED_DT    

PARENT1 CHILD1 100    01/17/2012
PARENT1 CHILD1 200    01/16/2012
PARENT1 CHILD2 300    01/14/2012
PARENT1 CHILD2 400    01/15/2012
```

The desired result set is record 1 and 4 -- i.e., PARENT1+CHILD1+100 (1/17 > 1/16), and PARENT1+CHILD2+400 (1/15 > 1/14).

If I do:

```
SELECT PARENT, CHILD, COUNT, MAX(CREATED_DT) FROM TABLE
GROUP BY PARENT, CHILD, COUNT
```

...then since the COUNT is different, it still selects all 4 rows. If I try:

```
SELECT PARENT, CHILD, MAX(CREATED_DT) FROM TABLE
GROUP BY PARENT, CHILD
```

...then I'm unsure how to go back and get the COUNT that I'm now missing.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can it be help you ?

```
SELECT [PARENT],
       [CHILD],
       [COUNT],
       [CREATED_DT]
FROM   (SELECT [PARENT],
               [CHILD],
               [COUNT],
               [CREATED_DT],
               Row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY [PARENT], [CHILD] ORDER BY
               created_dt desc)
                      AS
               'GroupId'
        FROM   t) a
WHERE  GroupId = 1
```

Comment: This is perfect -- had no idea that I could use PARTITION BY to do something similar to GROUP BY without the aggregation. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Like this?

```
SELECT 
t1.PARENT
, t1.CHILD
, t1.COUNT
, t1.CREATED_DT
FROM TABLE t1
WHERE
t1.CREATED_DT = (SELECT MAX(t2.CREATED_DT) 
              FROM TABLE t2 
              WHERE t1.PARENT = t2.PARENT
              AND   t1.CHILD = t2.CHILD)
```

Comment: +1 only note that this can return more than one result per group (which the OP did not mention).

Comment: I was remiss to mention the fact I did need only 1 result per group, so I think the PARTITION BY is actually going to end up as a better solution for this particular use case. Regardless, thank you.